# How to automatically export ER diagram(or relationships between tables) from table descriptions?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have some tables in a database, and table descriptions about these tables, tables' attributes(and data types), and whether they are PK (or FK), and in the data dictionary there can be text describing 
 the tables, too, but only a few. And here I want to extract relationships between these tables from information above automatically or semi-automatically if possible. I don't have any sql scripts that created these tables but I want to get the relations or export E-R diagram from them if possible.

People tend to infer relationships from the PK or FK in table schemas. But because tables are too many and this is really work consuming, so is there any way of doing it automatically or semi-automatically? The number of tables can be many, therefore the relations can be quite complicated.

I expect that potential method can output these tables' relationships, or E-R diagram if possible.

Comment: `I don't have any sql scripts that created these tables` how's that possible? What happens when you execute SHOW CREATE TABLE?

Comment: Yes, I'm only given those table descriptions, and I probably don't have access to those tables or scripts, therefore I have to infer the relationships from table descriptions instead of tables

Comment: Other than by analysing (optional) foreign key constraints, I suspect that you're on a hiding to nothing. SQL is a Structured Query Language. As the name suggests, the structure is explicitly provided within the query, and only implicit within the schema.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I wonder if there is an automatic tool or method that can infer the relationships from foreign key constraints. I'm faced with a problem where infos such as attributes/FK/PK are provided, but tables are too many and too complicated to draw an ER diagram all by yourself.

Comment: Mysql workbench can reverse engineer a database structure and the relationsips based on FKs. We cannot recommend you any products or tools because that's explicitly off topic here on SO. I only mention WB because you tagged your question with it. If you do have WB, then I do not understand your question.